# Gwt-Ext grid inside Gwt-Ext ColumnTree

Tags: gwt, grid, gwt-ext

I need to display a Gwt-Ext grid as a a node of a Gwt-Ext ColumnTree.

The idea is that if the user expand an item they would see a grid with headers with items under the headers.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

The tree allows you to use a template for the display, in the example in the site it s adding an image for the countries list, I d say the best you can do is put a panel that contains a grid on the side of it and add a listener to the tree so the grid reloads on click